# Linq enumeration yielded no result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is this expression built properly?

```
 var avTimes = db.AvailableTimes.Where(m => m.TimeOfAppointment >= new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 08, 00, 00)
                                              && m.TimeOfAppointment <= new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 16, 00, 00)
                                              && m.StateOfBooking == 1
                                              && m.ProviderId == id);
```

It gives "linq enumeration yielded no result" as output.

Comment: if db is data base context then seems like you have just IQurable query, in order to made actual request to the database you should use ToList(), ToDictionary() e.t.c. methods

Comment: If it yields no results, that means that there's no entity in your 'AvailableTimes' that matches the predicate you're providing it. Can you actually verify there's an entity in said collection that would pass all those checkes?

Comment: If you hover avTimes you can get the SQL generated by the query. That way you can check if there's actually any items in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enumeration yielding no result is the runtime telling you that your query did not find any matching results for your parameters. There are two ways to debug this:

1) Spin up SQL Profiler and start a trace, check to see the query getting generated and run that with query analyzer to understand your query better.

2) Trim your query back to no parameters, make sure it yields results and then add each parameter / refinement at a time and observer how the behaviour changes to understand it better.

Answer (score -1):

*Is this expression built properly?*

I would move the instaniation of the DateTime values out of the linq statement. Moving methods into the linq statement could lead to a exception like: *this can not be translated into a sql statement*.

```
DateTime dtTimeOfAppointmentFrom = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 08, 00, 00);
DateTime dtTimeOfAppointmentTo = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 16, 00, 00);

var avTimes = db.AvailableTimes.Where(m => m.TimeOfAppointment >= dtTimeOfAppointmentFrom
                                    && m.TimeOfAppointment <= dtTimeOfAppointmentTo
                                    && m.StateOfBooking == 1
                                    && m.ProviderId == id);
```

*linq enumeration yielded no result* just says that there are no rows found that meed your condition. So you could verify the result by typing the statement into a sql browser and comparing the results.